# Office 2013 Plus on Windows 8 x64: how to force update?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-office-2013

On a Windows 8 x64 VM that was fully updated I've installed and registered Office 2013 Plus from the TechNet ISO DVD image.

The ISO image has `Release Date: 10/25/2012`, and I choose manual updates just as I did in Windows 8 (I'm on the road often, I don't want automatic updates to kick in while on a slow or costly internet connection).

After installation, I did a reboot, then had the system check for manual updates through the control panel: none were available.

I know there have been various Office 2013 updates (at least in [Februari 2013](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2802843), in [March 2013](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2802843), in [April 2013](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2832224) in and [May 2013](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2847265)).

Since it is not a click-to-run install, the [manual Office 2013 click-to-run update mechanism mentioned here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/officeitpro/thread/4369357e-5de9-4755-8f2c-33ae948b14fb) does not work.

Also there is no "[File -> Account -> Update Options](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/support/change-recommended-update-and-diagnostic-settings-HA010369712.aspx#BM4)" (I tried Word, Excel, Access and PowerPoint)

How can I force the update to happen?

Comment: The updates to Office 2013 are pushed to `Windows Updates` after a period of time.  The very thread you linked to contained this information.

Comment: They are there, but I forgot to transform "Windows Update" into "Microsoft Update" (I expected the choice during the Office Install would automatically perform that transformation, but it wasn't). See my answer.

Comment: When downvoting: please indicate in your comments you did and why. That's the only way for me to improve my questions and answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it. EBCAK as I forgot the following steps to be performed once

Steps to fix:

1. Start the "Windows Update" window
2. Click the link in "Get updates for other Microsoft Products. [Find out more](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=230963)"
3. Internet Explorer starts at the [Microsoft Update page](http://fe1.update.microsoft.com/microsoftupdate/v6/vistadefault.aspx?ln=en-US) which detects you only have "Windows Update" configured and asks you if you want to configure "Microsoft Update" as well by agreeing to its [Terms of Use](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=9482).
4. Clicking there refreshes the same page into "Choose how Windows can install Updates" page (I took the "current settings" choice)
5. Click on the "Install" button
6. In the UAC screen, confirm you are an Administrator
7. Internet Explorer now refreshes the page to show "Find Windows Update using your Start Screen"
8. "Windows Update" now will find updates for other Microsoft products like Office 2013 as well (some 300 megabytes in my case)